# Why does a paragraph get taller as a contained span gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

In Firefox and Chrome and Safari (latest all, on Mac 10.6.8) if I use a browser's developer tools to *reduce* the font size of the following span, I can watch the height (line-height) of the paragraph *increase* by a few pixels :

```
<p style="line-height: 40px; background: red;">
    Some sample text some sample text.
    <span style="font-size: 100%;">As this span's text size gets smaller, the paragraph gets taller.</span>
</p>
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: This is a fascinating problem! Most interesting is that the paragraph loads with the incorrect line-height (41px) and then assumes the correct one (40px) after the span is sized down to 96%.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but try setting `display: inline-block` for the `span`. When I've these kind of problems this fix usually works...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I posted your sample html and inline css into js fiddle, here's the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sauhL/

I then used firebug to change `font-size:100%;` down to 99, 98 and so forth. You are right, when you go down 1 by 1 for the font-size value, the red box gets a little bigger for a second.

The problem is that you have line-height predetermined as `40px`, which causes what you called a 'bug' because line-height applied to different font sizes leads to different height renderings, and in the case of js fiddle, the linebreak is also a factor in the 'rendering' of the red box's height. After going down several points in `%`, there's no more expanding of the red box but rather a diminishing of size.

This is easily fixed by applying `line-height:100%` to the span which normalizes the height and makes sure there's no odd increases. You can expect these kinds of 'bugs' or anomalies when mixing fixed values (say `40px` for example) with percentual values (`100%` or whatever).

Hope this solves your question